# Autogenerated Guid is not working in new entities after using migrations

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, code-first

I started an ASP.NET MVC 5 web app with Entity Framework 6.4. At the beginning I had a context with 4 entities, therefore 4 tables in the database (apart from the tables for user management with Identity). Now I have needed to add another new entity related to a small Web API within the project. So, I have enabled migrations, added the new entity to the context, and added a new migration. All the IDs of my entities are of type `Guid` and are decorated with `Key` and `DatabaseGenerated` attributes.

An example of my model and metadata classes:

```
// MyModel.cs file
public partial class MyModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // More properties...

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

// MyModelMetadata.cs file
public class MyModelMetadata
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(ModelConstants.NameMaximumLength, MinimumLength = ModelConstants.NameMinimumLength)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(MyModelMetadata))]
public partial class MyModel{ }
```

When I create a new object of the *"old entities"* the new ID is generated properly in the database:

```
public async Task CreateModel(ModelDetailsViewModel vm, ApplicationUser user)
{
    ApplicationUser dbUser = this.context.Users.Find(user.Id);
    MyModel myModel = this.mapper.Map<MyModel>(vm);
    dbUser.MyModels.Add(myModel);
    await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

When I get `myModel` instance the value of `Id` is `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` and after `SaveChangesAsync()` is set to a new value.

When I added the new entity to the context to use it in the Web API controller, I added a new migration and changed it to add `identity: true` and `defaultValueSql: "newid()"` parameters to the Id:

```
public partial class NewEntityAdded : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.NewEntities",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true, defaultValueSql: "newid()"),
                    Timestamp = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    // More properties...
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
        
    }
    
    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.NewEntities");
    }
}
```

I add the new entity model with this code:

```
public async Task AddNewEntity(NewEntity newEntity)
{
    this.context.NewEntities.Add(newEntity);
    int results = await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The `newEntity` parameter comes with `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` `Id`, but after `SaveChangesAsync()` is not updated. So the first time the new entity is added, but in the second time an exception is thrown because the id already exists in the table.

To sum up, the GUIDs of the entities that existed before migrations are autogenerated properly, but the GUIDs of the entities added in new migrations are nor autogenerated in the database. Do you know why is this happening? And how can I solve it?

PD: I want to avoid setting the ID with `Guid.CreateNew()` method.

Comment: My assumption would be that you have to set the Id to Computed instead of Identity because you don’t want EF6 to mess with that value but generate it in your database sql script instead. If that doesn’t work, try catching the generated sql script in a database profiler and see what is actually happening there

Comment: When I want to generate IDs in the database I use ```[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]```, you can see it in ```MyModelMetadata``` class. There is no odd exception to catch, all new entities have {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} ID, so this is the error, key value can't be repeated.

Comment: Yes but your defaultValueSql could interfere with that, try the [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed] option or remove the defaultValueSql.